# “Has no exported member ionicBootstrap” (ionic2 Typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I have such an error: has no exported member ionicBootstrap.

ionicBootstrap was introduced in ionic-angular 2.0.0-beta.8. But I upgrade to the  2.0.0-beta.32 and the error is still remains. What will it can be?

Comment: Are you importing it like this: `import { ionicBootstrap } from 'ionic-angular';`?

Comment: Yes, `import {ionicBootstrap, Platform, MenuController, Nav} from 'ionic-angular';`

Comment: Could you add in your answer the output of running `ionic info` in the CLI?

Comment: here it is: https://gyazo.com/de19ce1325c3989004fb02187426b8cd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem as well. It turned out that I had two typings `ionic` and `cordova-ionic` which appeared to be outdated. I installed the starter to see if I had the same problem did not. The starter project did not have those typings so I removed them and ran `typings prune`. After my project rebuilt the error was gone. It looks like the typings are included in the `ionic-angular` package from npm.

Also from the screenshot it posted it looks like you still have `2.0.0-beta.7`. Try running `npm install --save @2.0.0-beta.8`

Comment: Thanks you! When I tried `npm install --save @2.0.0-beta.8` I had the error. This right: `npm install angular2@2.0.0-beta.8`

Comment: npm install --save angular2@2.0.0-beta.8

Answer (score 4):

I am new to Ionic and angular, but I think I have figured out this provider issue.  I was following this article to make a LocalState provider to allow pages to share information between each other in an Ionic2 app.
http://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-explanation-of-providers-in-ionic-2/

I ran into the ionicBootstrap issue mentioned in this question.  According to this source, 'You do not need ionicBootstrap anymore since rc0.'
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/no-exported-member-ionicbootstrap/66721

I created a provider with

```
ionic g provider LocalState
```

I added the following to app.module.ts:

```
import { LocalState } from '../providers/local-state';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Page1,
    Page2
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Page1,
    Page2
  ],
  providers: [
    LocalState
  ]
})
```

In app.component.ts and in each page's .ts file I added:

```
import { LocalState } from '../providers/local-state';
```

and added LocalState to the constructor:

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public localState: LocalState)
```

I could then read the members of LocalState in the page's .html file with:

```
{{localState.<insert member name>}}
```

I could update a LocalState member in methods in the page's .ts file.  For testing I called `localState.setMember()` in one page's constructor and other pages could read the updated value.

Comment: Depends on how big and how often you are using that service. I wouldn't suggest it, but big props that you found the work-around, I still haven't found a fix :( : "Which of these two you choose can matter a great deal. If you add it to the bootstrap then a single instance of the service will be created that all components in the application will share – making it a great way to share data between components. If you add the provider to an individual component, then a new instance will be created for just that one component."